# Padding stretching across entire screen

Tags: html, css

```css
body {background-color: white;}

.writing {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: black;
    text-align: Center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: White
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>My Website</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class=writing>

<h1 style="font-size:10px; padding-top: 20px;">IM HUNgry</h1>

<div style="padding-top: 20px">
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname"></label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
</form>
</body>
```

The padding border stretches across the entire screen. How can I change how wide the padding is? For example, I'd like to have the padding only be 200 pixels wide.

I'm sure this is a pretty basic question but I couldn't find an answer to this on google.

Answer (score 0):

The basic point to this is that properties such as padding would occupy the entire box. So instead of trying to make one box have two different heights,
HTML would suggest that you instead make 2 boxes, contained within a parent, and divide it that way.

```css
.child-with-padding {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  width:200px; /*This will be the part that ensures it only goes 200px*/
}

.parent {
 border: thin black solid;
}

.parent > div {
 display:inline-block;
 border: thin blue dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class=parent>
    <div class='child-with-padding'>This is padded</div>
    <div class='child-without-padding'>This is Not padded</div>
</div>
```